# Reset the JQuery star rating before adding the new one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rating

I have implemented ratings in Jquery for my website. 
Currently if the ratings are 4 and the same user adds a rating of 3, then the value 7 is saved in the database for ratings. 
So basically I just want to reset previous ratings and add the current rating(3) in the database as well as the webpage.

How can I achieve this ?

**Code :**

```
<li onmouseover="highlightStar(this,'rating');" onmouseout="removeHighlight();" onClick="addRating(this,'rating');">&#9733;</li>
  <li onmouseover="highlightStar(this,'rating');" onmouseout="removeHighlight();" onClick="addRating(this,'rating');">&#9733;</li>
  <li onmouseover="highlightStar(this,'rating');" onmouseout="removeHighlight();" onClick="addRating(this,'rating');">&#9733;</li>
  <li onmouseover="highlightStar(this,'rating');" onmouseout="removeHighlight();" onClick="addRating(this,'rating');">&#9733;</li>
  <li onmouseover="highlightStar(this,'rating');" onmouseout="removeHighlight();" onClick="addRating(this,'rating');">&#9733;</li>
```

**JQuery :**

```
function addRating(obj) {

    $('li').each(function(index) {
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $('#rating').val((index+1));
        if(index == $("li").index(obj)) {
            return false;   
        }
    });
}
```

**MySQL PHP code :**

```
if( empty($_POST)){

    }else if(strlen($_POST['currentReview']) >0 ){

        $currentReview = $_POST['currentReview'];
        $rating1 = intval($_POST['rating']) ;
        echo $rating1;
        $select_rating = "Select * from ratings where product_id = ". $product_id . "AND user_id = " .$user_id ;
        if(!($result =  mysql_query($select_rating, $databaseObj))){
            print("Couldn't execute select_rating");
            print $select_rating;
            die("My SQL error while inserting record");
    } else{
        echo "RATINGS::::::" ;
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
        print_r($row);
    }
        //print "Rating  value is $rating1  Char value : $_POST['rating'] </br>";
        $insert_query = "INSERT INTO ratings (product_id,site_id,user_id,rating, review) VALUES ($product_id,$site_id,$user_id,$rating1,\"$currentReview\")  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE review = \"$currentReview\",rating=$rating1;";

    }
    if(!($result =  mysql_query($insert_query, $databaseObj))){
            print("Couldn't execute insert_query");
            print $insert_query;
            die("My SQL error while inserting record");
    }
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking, could you please clarify?

Comment: I think we need to see the code you are using the add the rating to the database.

Comment: @TonyDeStefano I have added the mtsql php code :)

Comment: I am not seeing how a second rating from the same user would add the numbers together. What I do see are a bunch of security and deprecation issues. Also, it would be helpful to also see the code that posts to the PHP script (is it AJAX? is it a form post?). I assume you have a UNIQUE constraint on product_id + user_id as well?

Answer (score 0):

Check the database for the user, if there is a result, do am update instead of insert

```
if (mysql_query("SELECT rating FROM ratings WHERE user_id = $user_id", $databaseObj)) {
   $insert_query =" UPDATE ratings SET rate = $rating1 WHERE user_id = $user_id";
 }
```